# How to run Linux commands with JavaScript at the client

Tags: javascript, linux, web

I have a final project and I want to know how to run Linux commands of network emulator [NetEm](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem), like `sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem loss 5%` with JavaScript in the client.

Comment: Is the JS running on the server with node.js?

Comment: It's possible with Node, impossible without. Also, this question has nothing to do with PHP. I've removed this tag, but please only tag the appropriate languages in future.

Comment: @Webdesigner how I can know whether or not!

Comment: You asking about Javascript so I assume you have some code. Is this Server Based code or Browser based code?

Comment: I did not understand your question but I want to execute commands at the client machine connected on a local network

Comment: Javascript can't execute commands on the client machine. If you run Javascript on the server using Node.js, it can execute commands on the server.

Comment: exeste it a solution with another tool !! :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with another language like Java
you create an HTTP request, send your command with ajax and it will be executed with your java application.

Comment: but my application web is realize in php how I can do it !!!

Comment: there is no problem , php or javascript or any language you can send an HTTP request.

Comment: so you must create a new app with another language , like java or .net 
you will make api that it execute commands